# I'm trying to provision Kubernetes executor in Gitlab with caching enabled. I've used EFS for caching. But it is not working

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner

Values file of K8's executor Helm chart is as follows -

```
image:
  registry: registry.gitlab.com
  image: gitlab-org/gitlab-runner

useTini: false

imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

replicas: 1

gitlabUrl: https://gitlab.com

runnerRegistrationToken: "xxxxxxxx"

unregisterRunners: true

terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 120

concurrent: 5

checkInterval: 10

rbac:
  create: true
  rules: []

runners:  
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      executor = "kubernetes"
      builds_dir = "/builds"
      [runners.kubernetes]
        namespace = "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
        image = "alpine"
        privileged = true
        poll_interval = 5
        poll_timeout = 3600
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.pvc]]
          # CI_CONCURRENT_ID identifies parallel jobs of the same runner. "gwl-runner-shared-pvc-$CI_CONCURRENT_ID"
          name = "gwl-runner-shared-pvc"
          mount_path = "/builds"

  tags: "Docker,Runner"

  name: "runner-k8s-executor"
```

I have created PV, PVC and storage class for EFS as a pre-requisite.
Issue is no caching is happening. Instead when I'm running jobs by removing [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.pvc]] block , i.e. running jobs without caching, they're bit faster than with the cached one.

If someone has done this , can you share your code for both values file as well as a sample pipeline where you've implemented this.

I was expecting that in the iterations other than first one, the pipeline should run fast by picking up the cache via EFS.
Also note that I've used concurrent as 5. Since I want to run 5 concurrent jobs.